# Call 2 functions in is

Tags: javascript, forms, function

I have 2 functions that work fine on their own. Using them in a form. I can call them in one onclick event, however I would like to place both in one script with the first called validate() but only call second function display() if information is correct.  So if validate() is called and info not correct they get an alert and returns to form true, if info correct then display() is called. Any help appreciated.

```
 function validate() {

  // Get the value of the input field with id="QTY"
  var x = document.forms["confirm"]["QTY"].value;

// If x is Not a Number or less than one
  if (isNaN(x) || x &lt; 1 ) {
      alert("Quantity - Minimum 1 required please");
   return true;
 }

 }



  function display()
 {
  var x=document.confirm.qty.value; 
  var y=document.confirm.price.value; 
  var z=document.confirm.total.value;

  var confirm = window.confirm('Quantity:' + x + '\nPrice Each: ' + y + '\nTotal Price: ' + z + '\n\nConfirm your order?' );
 }if(result)
 {
        // user has pressed ok

 }
else
        // user has pressed cancel
{
      document.getElementById("myform").reset();

    }
```

Comment: `if (validate()) { display(); } else { alert('whatever'); }`?

Comment: fix your code formatting first, and second you can just call `display()` within `validate()` if the validation has passed?

Comment: Thank you both. I'm very new to this and am learning. What you have suggested I am a little confused. How do I call display () within validate() please. I'm trying to understand. Sorry if I sound dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is customary to have validate return true if the validation passes.

```
function validate() {

    // Get the value of the input field with id="QTY"
    var x = document.forms["confirm"]["QTY"].value;

    // If x is Not a Number or less than one
    if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 ) {
      alert("Quantity - Minimum 1 required please");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
 }



 function display()
 {
    var x=document.confirm.qty.value; 
    var y=document.confirm.price.value; 
    var z=document.confirm.total.value;

    var confirm = window.confirm('Quantity:' + x + '\nPrice Each: ' + y + '\nTotal Price: ' + z + '\n\nConfirm your order?' );

    if(confirm)
    {
        // user has pressed ok

    }
    else
        // user has pressed cancel
    {
      document.getElementById("myform").reset();

    }
}

if (validate()) { display(); }
```

If you give us more information about the html and glue code we could help better.